# Query of List of Functions

Tags: r

I have the following example code from a course in coursera

```
makeVector <- function(x = numeric()) {
    m <- NULL
    set <- function(y) {
            x <<- y
            m <<- NULL
    }
    get <- function() x
    setmean <- function(mean) m <<- mean
    getmean <- function() m
    list(set = set, get = get,
         setmean = setmean,
         getmean = getmean)
}
```

However , i dont understand the significant of the last list function. Can some one explain it ? Thank you.

Comment: the last line of a function, if not assigned to a value, contains what the function will return: makeVector(3) is a list of set, get, setmean, getmean

Comment: Explicit way of writing it would be `return(list(...))`. If one is calling a function many times, statistically significant gain in speed may be gained in implicitly returning the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final call to `list()` builds a new list object and returns it from `makeVector()` (because it's the last statement in the function).

The new list object is populated with four components: `set`, `get`, `setmean`, and `getmean`. The value of each of these four components is populated with a function that was defined dynamically during the execution of the `makeVector()` function.

All four functions are a little bit special in that they all will end up sharing a pointer to the execution environment that was in effect at the time the `makeVector()` function was executing for that particular invocation of itself. Because they variously read and write the variables `x` and `m` that were local to that invocation, they all end up sharing those variables as pseudo-private variables. This is sort of an implementation of the functional pattern of object-oriented programming, where temporary local variables are closured by a new set of dynamically defined functions within a temporary scope. This pattern is seen in various languages, including R, Perl, and JavaScript.

Also note that the writability of the shared variables only works because the superassignment operator (`<<-`) was used to assign to them from the scope of the dynamic mutator functions (`set()` and `setmean()`). If the normal assignment operator (`<-`) had been used, then a new local variable would be temporarily created in the scope of the dynamic mutator function itself at the time it would be called, which would not affect the closure variables.